What is the gravity above which launching into space is hindered?
I'm building a scenario where humanity meets an alien society with a technology comparable to that we have in the 2000's and beyond. Its technological level is comparable to ours. They have tapped alternative energy resources, they are making great advances in medicine, they begin restoring ecologies without compromising food production, and they are making great advances in astrophysics. However, they have one thing that sets them apart from us: They live on a super-Earth planet with a much higher gravity. The gravity is so high that they are unable to launch anything into space, not even a satellite into orbit. Based on their level of technology, their propulsion system is similar to ours - rocket engines. No warp drive yet.
They have circumvented the issue by launching lighter-than-air crafts into the stratosphere. Their denser atmosphere allows them to launch blimps with the necessary payloads and instruments, including solar panels and batteries for their night run. Along with airborne relay stations, blimp-borne instruments established a communication network and a GPS system which span the globe. The blimps have the necessary means to compensate for wind drift and remain stationary above the desired location. "Space" telescopes are periodically pushed upward via rockets. They help the telescope to pop-up higher into the atmosphere, enough time for a clearer vision before the rocket runs out of fuel and the telescope descends into the lower atmosphere.
So based on their current technology, comparable to ours, what is the gravity, above which, they (or us) would not be able to launch anything into orbit, let alone into space?

When the specific impulse becomes so low that for any amount of fuel the engine won't be able to produce enough thrust to accelerate it out of the atmosphere and to orbital velocity.
If you have a really good launch trajectory and maybe some aerodynamic assistance, you can neglect that first part and just wonder "how long does it take for the engine to get the rocket to orbital speed, and will it last that long?"
Specific impulse conveniently acts as a measure of how long the engine can hold a given amount of fuel (notably not payload like the engine itself, the fuel tanks, and the scientists and instruments onboard) up against surface gravity. On Earth, you calculate this as $v_e/9.81$, where $v_e$ is the effective exhaust velocity. For some other planet, you'd substitute 9.81 for its gravity to find the specific impulse. Then, you can calculate the necessary orbital speed and see how long it'll take the engine to accelerate a craft to orbital speed, then see if that many seconds is more or less than the engine's specific impulse. If it takes longer to get to orbit than the engine can support 1 $g_\mathrm{planet}$ for, then no matter what happens, it won't be able to keep the spacecraft in the sky long enough to reach orbit. Otherwise, you're okay.
Figuring out exactly where that limit is is hard. I'll leave it to you: find the limit where the gravity is high enough that the time to reach orbital velocity exceeds the engine's specific impulse.
Of course, I have to leave it to you because I'd need to know your planet's radius, mass, and atmospheric altitude and the specific impulse of the best launcher engine your aliens have access to. I don't have any of that information. For reference, one of the best (or at least cooler) launcher engines that is efficient in space and in atmosphere might be the RS-25 main engine, used on the Space Shuttle. It boasts a specific impulse of 366 seconds in atmosphere and 452.3 seconds in vacuum. Accounting for a little Technological Development™, you might call your best launcher specific impulse 475 seconds on Earth, which equates to an exhaust velocity of about 4.6 kilometers per second (4,650 m/s). So, since you know your planet's gravity, you can calculate an RS-25's specific impulse, and then see if it can get to orbit.

In this realm ISP effectively tells you what fraction of your vehicle must be fuel.  There is no inherent limit other than this.  If that fraction is higher than what you can build the rocket doesn't reach orbit.
